# Invalid column _count when using Contacts.Groups._COUNT to get Contacts Groups?

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-sdk-1.6

**Problem 1.**

I have this class:

```
public class ContactGroups {

    // Form an array specifying which columns to return.
    String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.Groups._ID,
            Contacts.Groups._COUNT, Contacts.Groups.NAME, Contacts.Groups.NOTES };

    public Cursor getList(Activity act) {

        Uri contacts = Contacts.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
             // using the debugger code kills here
            Cursor managedCursor = act.managedQuery(contacts, projection, 
                null, 
                null 
             , null
                );
        return managedCursor;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getColumnData(Cursor cur) {
        ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

            String name;
            String notes;
            int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Groups.NAME);
            int notesColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Groups.NOTES);

            do {
                // Get the field values
                name = cur.getString(nameColumn);
                notes = cur.getString(notesColumn);
                aa.add(name);
                // Do something with the values.

            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        }
        return aa;
    }

}
```

I am calling this as:

```
ContactGroups mGrp= new ContactGroups();
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mGrp.getColumnData(mGrp.getList(this)));
myListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

And having:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

I get a Source not found error
and a Logcat error

`ERROR/DatabaseUtils(617): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _count`

Does somebody know why?

**Problem 2.**

Where do I create manually contact groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Contacts.Groups](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Groups.html) is deprecated. You should use [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

And the constants you may be interested in are under [ContactsContract.Groups](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html), especially SUMMARY_COUNT for the count

Comment: I use sdk1.6 api level 4. They don't exists yet on it.